# How to read Inexhaustible data from LAN port in C++

Tags: c++, tcp, buffer, boost-asio, fstream

This is my code for read a data from file:

```
void sendfile(string pathname)
{
  ifstream ifs(pathname, std::ifstream::in);

  if(ifs.fail()) 
  {
      throw "error opening";
  }

  const size_t BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
  char* buffer;
  buffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];

  // get file size
  ifs.seekg(0, ios::end);
  int file_size = ifs.tellg();
  ifs.seekg(0, ios::beg);

  cout <<"File size : "<<file_size<< "bytes"<<endl;

  unsigned char *data = new unsigned char [file_size];

  ifs.read((char*)data, file_size);

  for(int i=0; i < file_size; i += 2)
  {
    if (data[i] == 0xAF 
    && data[i+1] == 0xDB 
    && data[i+2] == 0xAA 
    && data[i+3] == 0x00)
    {
        if (data[i + BUFFER_SIZE - 4] == 0xFF
        && data[i + BUFFER_SIZE - 3] == 0xAA 
        && data[i + BUFFER_SIZE - 2] == 0xDF
        && data[i + BUFFER_SIZE - 1] == 0x00)
        {
            cout << "Packet" << endl;
        }
    }
  }


  delete[] data;
  ifs.close();
```

But now I try to read Inexhaustible data from file or serial port byte by byte and check them to HEADER and FOOTER then send data with TCP/IP port to server.
I have written the client and server part codes and now I am trying to get this part of the inexhaustible data byte by byte. I mean, I am still unaware of the next byte and I want to check the HEADER and FOOTER and then send the packet[1024 byte].
using boost::asio for this example.

State machine:
[image]

What should I do?

**UPDATE**

Client header file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <bitset>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
using namespace boost::asio;
using ip::tcp;
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using byte = unsigned char;

class Client
{
public:
    Client(io_context& io_context,
        char host[10],
        unsigned int port)
        : socket_(io_context)
    {
        start(host, port);
    }
    ~Client()
    {
        stop();
    }
private:
    enum { CLIENT_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 };
    char buffer[CLIENT_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE];
    boost::asio::streambuf receive_buffer;
    tcp::socket socket_;
    void start(char[10], unsigned int);
    void stop();
};
```

Server Header file:

```
TCPServer::TCPServer(io_context& io_service, char host[10], unsigned int port)
    : io_context_(io_service),
    acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port))
{
    cout << "Server is running ..." << endl;
    cout << "Server: got connection from " << host << " port " << port << endl;
    //Timer await
    timer = new deadline_timer(io_service, boost::posix_time::milliseconds(3100));
    timer->wait();
    std::cout << "Blocking wait(): " << 3 << " second-wait\n";
    start_accept();
}
//Creates a socket and initiates an asynchronous accept operation to wait for a new connection.
void TCPServer::start_accept()
{
    // socket definition
    connection = connectionHandler::create(io_context_);
    // asynchronous accept operation and wait for a new connection.
    acceptor_.async_accept
    (
        connection->socket(),
        boost::bind(&TCPServer::handle_accept,
        this, 
        connection,
        boost::asio::placeholders::error)
    );
}
//It services the client request, and then calls start_accept() to initiate the next accept operation.
void TCPServer::handle_accept(connectionHandler::pointer connection, const boost::system::error_code& err)
{
    if (!err)
    {
        connection->start();
    }
    start_accept();
}
void TCPServer::stop()
{
    connection->stop();
}
```

Comment: please show a [mre] of what you've implemented so far and what isn't working

Comment: The mention of "packet" suggests to me that your networking code is incorrect - TCP/IP is not a packet-oriented protocol, but an unstructured stream of octets.

Comment: @AlanBirtles This code works but my data is sent byte by byte by client and I have to check it and continue if it is in HEADER pattern match.

Comment: @molbdnilo i know, in this example I have written the TCP/IP server/client and works. but We have a IPC client and send data[packet] every second and I should to get packet and check it then unpack and send to another servers with TCP/IP.

Comment: from what you write, it is really unclear what the problem is - you show code for reading a file, yet your problem seems to be somewhere else -  can you elaborate on where exactly you are stuck? you mention boost::asio, what have you tried with that?

Comment: @codeling not yet, My problem is that code. the code work for limited data but don't work for unlimited data such as stream. have a LAN port to send data every second and I should to get data and send packer [1024 Byte] to another server. My problem is that I want to buffer this unlimited data and then send it. But I have to look at the data according to the pattern I gave above. What should i do?

Comment: The FSM diagram is inscrutable because we have no way of knowing what the labels mean. You should just explain what HEADER/FOOTER "pattern match" mean, instead of how you imagine doing that, translated into unintelligible images. I'm pretty sure the answer can be 3 lines of Asio given a good explanation

Comment: If I can understand you correctly, you should be reading the data and checking it for the beginning of the header; from this point you should be pushing back each next byte to a vector until you hit  the end-of-packet bytes, and then the vector will contain  the information  you're after.